# Ubuntu Trial version

Tags: 16.04, windows-vista

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my old laptop. I am still in the trial version, is it the same as if i would install in on my drive and if I do can i still go back t my old OS(Windows Vista) and will I lose all my files?

Thanks.

Comment: What is "trail version"?

Comment: At the beginning it will ask you if you want to try ubuntu or if you want to install it directly

Comment: I see. You can install Ubuntu and keep Windows installed, or replace Windows with Ubuntu. In the latter case, you'll lose your files.

Comment: Fixed the confusing typo in your title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Try Ubuntu" environment does NOT touch your hard drive.

- The default "Try Ubuntu" environment is also *not persistent*: Anything you change or save will be forgotten at reboot.

Simply unplug the USB and reboot, and your computer should boot into your old Windows normally.